# Read a JSON file using JavaScript

Tags: json, django, file-handling

I am using the Django framework for web-development. I want to read a JSON file and print its contents on a web-page.

**Here's my script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src = "file:///home/pragna/myproject/myapp/templates/myapp/segment2.json">
</script>

<script>
    var mydata = JSON.parse(jsonstr);
    alert(mydata[0].text);
</script>
```

I have stored my JSON file in the following format:

```
jsonstr = [
     {
         "text": "this is the text",
         "name" : "thisisme"
     },

     {
         "text": "some more text",
         "name" :"thisisaname"
     }
]
```

When I run the server, there is no 404 error when the the webpage requests the file, however, no alert comes up either.

Comment: The file isn't proper json.` jsonstr` needed surrounding double quotes and the the everything should be wrapped in `{}', that is the first thing is { and the last }. But that said it may not matter, because as far as I can see it's being treated more like an array.

Answer (score 1):

> When I run the server, there is no 404 error when the the webpage
>   requests the file

No 404 error in the server you mean. The browser console will still show you a 404 error because you are using a file:/// url to load your JSON.

```
<script type="text/javascript", src ="file:///home/pragna/myproject/myapp/templates/myapp/segment2.json">    </script>
```

This should be either http://, https:// or a relative url like /segment2.json

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to parse content as it is JSON already.

Try this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src ="file:///home/pragna/myproject/myapp/templates/myapp/segment2.json"></script>
    <script>
        alert(jsonstr[0].text);
    </script>
```

should work.

That said, [XmlHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) is a better way to go in this case I think.

Answer (score 0):

no need to parse

```
alert('{{ jsonstr.0.text }}');
```

Comment: Does not this return a string that says `{{ jsonstr.0.text }}`? Because it is in a quote

Answer (score 0):

You will get **404**, because you are trying to access a file inside your local computer with `file:///` prefix, and here is your demo in real word:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src ="http://www.mocky.io/v2/5797d7190f00005c0ef0809e"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 alert(jsonstr[0].text);
</script>
```